# Software to connect a Professional Digital Camera

Tags: 12.04, camera

My brother has a Canon EOS 310 which frankly scares the bejesus out of me when I hold it because is heavy (and expensive). Anyway I am trying to get the pictures from the camera to Ubuntu but it only detects it as a pen drive. What software exists to open, view and extract the images from this camera.

Comment: is he using the raw format?

Comment: He said yes. I am guessing they will be some huge size images then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found one and not anywhere, inside Software Center. Darktable:

[image]

But I still could not fix the problem about getting the images. The problem was that I needed to unmount the camera. It can't be mounted if I want to connect darktable and extract the images.

Love Ubuntu more everyday. I mean it has everything.

Comment: Did you have any trouble getting Dark Table to import your photos?  I have a Canon camera packed full of wedding photos and I can't figure out how to get Ubuntu to download them.

Comment: No problem at all. The only thing is that you need to make sure that the memory disc does not get mounted by ubuntu. It has to be unmounted in order for darktable to read the camera directly. Is not like a typical camera that you can search the SD memory card like a pen drive. In this case I have to unmount anything related to the camera in order for Darktable to read the files.

Answer (score 0):

There should be alot of files a couple of folders down may be like "DCIM" and then files like DCS00001.RAW or some other extension, it differs per camera.

You need to install a program to read those files, I use RawTherapee , Search for "raw" in software center and you should be able to find a couple of different programs that will work. RawTherapee works very similarly to Photoshop Raw.

As for getting the images, some cameras do not have support for getting them off with usb the normal way (in support of their propitiatory software to get them off) so you may need to take the memory card out and use a memory card reader.

Comment: You are correct mateo but they were not the images I were looking for. Not even any of the images the camera had. They were so weird stuff that maybe is used by the camera as cache or something. I did take out the memory card but it was huge. It was the same size as my card reader. Even fatter.

Comment: That would be Compact Flash(ironic it is not as "compact" as the others) you would need a new reader, I guess your current one is just memory stick and SD.

Comment: Yes it is one of those cheap 52 in 1 things.

Comment: @mateo_salta How can I access these DCIM files directly in the Terminal?

Comment: @theJollySin never tried it myself, since i use gui for graphics purpose, but for batch editing this may be of help http://scribblesandsnaps.wordpress.com/tag/ufraw/ make sure to install the programs it says to run first, like "ufraw"